# Mysql : How to remove NOT NULL constraints from all the tables in a given schema

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `Mysql(5.7)` database.

Suppose I have a schema by name `main_schema` and I have 100 tables in that schema.

I want to remove all `null constraints` for all the tables.

How can achieve it?

Any programmatic approach or a single `SQL` query which can do that?

Comment: You will have to build 100 ALTER statements from information_schema.columns and submit them via dynamic sql see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35073/modify-all-tables-in-a-database-with-a-single-command

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do this to update every null value in a table but I imagine the reason why your asking this is because you don't want to do this 100 times.

```
update tablename set fieldname = "textstring" where fieldname is null;
```

Comment: The question is 'I want to remove all null constraints for all the tables.' you would do this with an ALTER statement not an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Agree, i want to remove null constraints from table not remove null values from table entries.

Comment: You could also try when creating your tables to require values to be not null like so

CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE
);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourColumn columnType NULL
```

Comment: I know but I have to execute 100's and 1000's of queries.
I want to know if I can do it in less number of queries